# On boot firmware request for intel GMA 3100 chipset timing out

Tags: xen, boot, timeout, gentoo, firmware

I am currently in the process of installing a Gentoo linux box with a Vanilla 2.6.29-r5 kernel with [gentoo-xen-kernel patches](http://code.google.com/p/gentoo-xen-kernel/) in order to run the Xen Hypervisor.

After rebooting with the new kernel, the booting process seemed to hang on:

```
[    0.863005] platform microcode: firmware: requesting intel-ucode/06-0f-07
[   60.863442] Microcode Update Driver: v2.00-xen <tigran@aivazian.fsnet.co.uk>, Peter Oruba
```

Apparently the firmware request times out after 60 seconds (`/sys/class/firmware/timeout`) and booting just continues.

I have done some [research](http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0904.3/00198.html) and have found that on RHEL-4 this problem was related to the mount of /sys changed and the firmware.agent hotplug script couldn't parse the line correctly.

However I am having some difficulty tracking down how to fix this on Gentoo.

Any and all ideas are greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: This bug is still valid with gentoo xen-sources 2.6.34-r4.

Answer (score 0):

Try to compile "/dev/cpu/microdode - microcode support" as a module in your kernel and load it later